# Why was this question of mine closed by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

A moderator (ACuriousMind) refuses to open this question on physics forum. He claims it needs to be more focused.

This question is related to double-slit experiment.
Is this question terribly unclear and a bad use of English language?
Here is the question I posted:

In the double-slit experiment, is there a clear relationship between the unobserved screen's constructive interference pattern and the observed screen's particle behavior pattern?

Comment: The people that reopened my question was not this fellow ACuriousMind. And all of a sudden those same people that reopened it and without doing anything to my question, they closed it again. This is the most childish behavior I have come across in sometime. All of a sudden the very question that was once clear to them, they decided it is not clear. This ACuriousMind closed another question of mine single handedly again. I want to block this guy from bothering me.

Comment: I know you're frustrated, but please don't fabricate false statements. (1) Your [first question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/657245/revisions) was *not* reopened by the same people who closed it, and (2) Your other questions [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/658361/revisions) and [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/656543/revisions) were not closed by a moderator.

Answer (score 11):

In case you are talking about [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/657245/50583), it has been reopened by [regular reopen review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/353623) around the same time you posted this question. This site does not work in real-time and after I closed your question I had no further interaction with it, i.e. I neither actively refused to reopen it nor did I reopen it.

Note that the [first version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/657245/1) I unilaterally closed was very different and read more like a stream-of-consciousness than a well-formed question about physics.